# DocumentDB Scaling with Partitioned Collections

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am migrating from managing several single instance **10gb** partitions per tenant to a more scalable solution utilizing partition keys **(tenantId)**. Previously I partitioned by collection but am interested in the cost savings I will gain by moving to partitioned collections since most of my tenants will not need more than **1-5gb** of storage. I set up my initial collection as a 10gb instance with the lowest RU settings (for testing and cost savings) like so:

[image]

Now when it comes time to scale I went back to the portal, clicked on scale and I do not see a way to increase my 10gb partition to greater capacity:

[image]

The pricing tier is locked and I am unable to increase my collection size past 10gb.

Couple of questions:

**1. Is the only way around this for me to make a support request?** The portal states this if you roll over the info icon but and it vaugely references a better way to scale is being developed? However I am looking for some clear information on this since making support requests is untenable in production scenarios as I may need to increase (and decrease) capacity on the fly!

**2. Is there (or will there be) a way to automatically scale partitions?** For example can I allow my initial 10gb to scale to 50gb in 10gb increments automatically - but alert me to allow it to go past 50gb?

**3. Is there (or will there be) a way to scale partitions programmatically via the C# SDK?**

**4. What is the incremental unit for scaling?** I'm assuming it is in **10gb** increments but I could not find any clear documentation on this.

**5. Should I assume that my PartitonKey is still limited by the 10gb storage restriction? If so: is there an upcoming (or existing) scenario that would allow a PartitionKey to grow outside of this 10gb boundary?** Again I am having to make assumptions here as the documentation is sporadic and very vague!

Comment: If you need to have automated scaling for your DocumentDb collections, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - autoscaling of Document DBs is not available thru Azure

Answer (score 1):

From [DocumentDB Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/), we could know that each collection is billed hourly based on the amount of data stored (in GBs) and throughput reserved in units of 100 RUs/second. And as you said, currently it only enables us to [adjust throughput level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-set-throughput) under Scale blade on Azure portal.

Besides, according to your description, we could find that you created single-partition collection with the lowest throughput capacity, if you’d to scale it to higher throughput (>10,000 RU/s) or larger data storage (>10GB), you could use the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool to migrate the data from the single-partition collection to a partitioned collection. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#migrating-from-single-partition-to-partitioned-collections) shows how to migrate from a single-partition collection to a partitioned collection, please refer to it.

Comment: According to what you are saying the only way I can start using partitioned collections (without having to worry about doing a migration at some later date) is to start with a 250GB plan? That seems a little silly to me. Especially since the cost is 6x as much if I set it to the very lowest RU level. This is also an incredible amount of unused storage I'd be paying for!

Comment: Does this also mean that if I choose a 250GB plan and then outgrow it that I will have to send in a request to increase this amount (let's say 500GB) and then have to migrate 250GB of data to the new 500GB plan?